# Filling nan values

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that contains nan values. These values are dependent on another variable, and I am trying to clean the data using it. I write a code to replace the nan values but it doesn't work. The code is:

```
df.loc[(df["house"]=="rented") & (df["car"]=="yes")]["debt"].fillna(2, inplace=True)
```

Comment: It´d be great if you could show your `df.head()` result

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Conditional that returns a boolean Series with column labels specified

```py
df.loc[df['shield'] > 6, ['max_speed']]

            max_speed
sidewinder          7
```

Based on the documentation it should be converted to this:

```py
df.loc['filter','selected column']
```

Give it a try like this:

```py
df.loc[(df["house"]=="rented") & (df["car"]=="yes"), ["debt"]].fillna(2, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch df.loc to

```
for val in df.index:
    if (df["house"][val] == "rented") and (df["car"][val] == "yes"):
        df["debt"][val] = 2
```

If I understand you correctly, you do not want to just fill in the na values. Rather,  you'd like to fill the na values only when house is rented and you have a car. To fill all na values at df index "debt"

```
df["debt"].fillna(2, inplace=True)
```

should be used rather then your second line of code.